# what library does LED belong to in Pspice?

Tags: led, pspice

I am a student and new to Pspice, I am given the following example circuit

[image]

and asked to created the following circuit,

[image]

which I have this

[image]

I think I have my circuit designed correctly. However, I am having trouble with finding the correct diode. I have tried different library such as diode, ediode, diode_bridge, on_diode and infineon, but the diodes from these library don't give a current of 20mA(typically lower than that). I also tried to find discrete.olb, however it's not in my capture library.... Is there any other library contains the 2legs led like the diodes in example circuit?I think the reason why I am not getting 20mA is because of the diode?

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen [here](https://www.pspice.com/optoelectronics/leds#block-system-main) on the PSPICE website, you should be able to find all of the LED models in the Optoelectronics->LEDs library.